# How to perform OrderBy followed by OrderByDescending?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

I have a collection where I am trying to sort the records first by Quarter and then inside the quarter by highest amounts. My code so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> lstTest = new List<Test>();
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), amount = 2500 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), amount = 10000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 5), amount = 4000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 10), amount = 40000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 15), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 25), amount = 12000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 2, 5), amount = 38000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 2, 10), amount = 38000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 2, 15), amount = 4000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 2, 20), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 2, 20), amount = 20000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 3, 15), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 3, 20), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 3, 20), amount = 4000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 3, 31), amount = 1000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 4, 9), amount = 50000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 4, 11), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 4, 21), amount = 1000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 4, 21), amount = 10000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 4, 28), amount = 5000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 5), amount = 45000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 7), amount = 98000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 9), amount = 7000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 25), amount = 2000 });
            lstTest.Add(new Test { dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 31), amount = 1000 });

            var result = lstTest.Select(x => new
            {
                Amount = x.amount,
                Date = x.dt,
                MonthDiff = GetMonthsDiff(DateTime.Now, x.dt),
                Quater = GetQuarter(DateTime.Now, x.dt)
            }).OrderBy(o=>o.Quater).ToList();

            foreach (var res in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Amount = {0}  Date= {1} MonthDiff= {2}  Quater= {3}", res.Amount, res.Date, res.MonthDiff, res.Quater);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static string GetQuarter(DateTime start, DateTime end)// int month)
        {
            int month = GetMonthsDiff(start, end);
            string quarter =  month <= 3 ? "Q1" : (month >= 4 && month <= 6) ? "Q2" : (month >= 7 && month <= 9) ? "Q3" : "Q4";
            return quarter;
        }



        public static int GetMonthsDiff(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            if (start > end)
                return GetMonthsDiff(end, start);

            int months = 0;
            do
            {
                start = start.AddMonths(1);
                if (start > end)
                    return months;

                months++;
            }
            while (true);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public DateTime dt { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output is

[image]

If I do `OrderBy(o=>o.Quater).OrderByDescending(o=>o.Amount)` the output changes to

[image]

That is *it is first sorting by Quarter and then by Amount*.

But I am looking for **first sort by Quarter and within the Quarter sort by Amount descending**.

The desired output is

[image]

What needs to be modified in the program so as achieve the target?

Comment: You have a typo: it's Quarter, not Quater.

Comment: Change your second OrderBy to ThenBy. google for "Enumerable ThenBy"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sort by a single property only. You can return the sort fields as <s>an anonymous object</s> tuple.

In C# 7 you can write :

```
OrderBy(o => (o.Quarter,o.Amount));
```

In previous versions :

```
OrderBy(o => Tuple.Create(o.Quarter,o.Amount));
```

If you want to use different sort orders you have to specify the fields one at a time, eg:

```
OrderBy(o=>o.Quarter).ThenByDescending(o=>o.Amount);
```

Or you can use query syntax to make the code cleaner:

```
var result = ( from x in lstTest
               let o = new {
                            Amount = x.amount,
                            Date = x.dt,
                            MonthDiff = GetMonthsDiff(DateTime.Now, x.dt),
                            Quarter = GetQuarter(DateTime.Now, x.dt)
                          }
               orderby o.Quarter, o.Amount descending
               select o
             ).ToList()
```

Comment: The first part is wrong - you can't sort by anonymous type. While the compiler implements value equality for anonymous types, it does not implement comparison.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right. It works with tuples, though, both old and new.

Answer (score 11):

replace

```
OrderBy(o=>o.Quater).OrderByDescending(o=>o.Amount)
```

with

```
OrderBy(o=>o.Quater).ThenByDescending(o=>o.Amount)
```

> [ThenByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534489(v=vs.110).aspx) performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a
>   sequence in descending order by using a specified comparer.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are sorting the list two times, you are getting the output of the final sort only, if you want to perform the second sort over the sorted result of the first then you have to make use of [`ThenByDescending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534489(v=vs.110).aspx)(if you want the second sort in descending order or else use `ThenBy()`) followed by OrderBy as like this:

```
var sortedItems = lstTest.OrderBy(o=>o.Quater).ThenByDescending(o=>o.Amount);
```

I have modified the code here in [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D6QMKy), you can check the output in the fiddle